# Calculation between minutes with a Power BI calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between two rows from the row below to the one above bearing in mind the end of quarter or the change in Game, but I'm not being available to do it.

The Google Drive Link with the xlsx: [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SlzwO6bgBBgrftwrVPGRVBE9KkIy_YqJ?usp=share_link](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Example of the expected Result with a Game (ExpectedResult Tab in xlsx). The ExpectedResult is calculated with the difference between the cell and the one above, bearing in mind the end of quarters or the change in games.

[image]

Once we could calculate the ExpectedResult value, I would like to sum up the value (like it was a Pivot Table in Excel).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this measure-

```
M = 

var current_quarter = min(your_table[Full_Quarter])
var current_time = min(your_table[Time_Def])

var prev_time =
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table[Time_Def]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table),
        your_table[Full_Quarter] = current_quarter
            && your_table[Time_Def] < current_time
    )
)

return current_time - prev_time
```

And set the measure type as marked in the below image-

[image]

Comment: Hi mkRabbani!

I tried your code but returned all 0:00:01 no matter the minutes in Time_Def column.

Comment: Check the data type of your column Time_def. It should work.